# Optimize performance - writing out Prime Numbers

Tags: python

The issue is **Prime Numbers** -that the solution is not implemented effectively.

I hear about **eratosthenes sieve**.

---

What are the other methods of implementing prime numbers - in a more efficient way?

```py
n = int(input())
suma = 0
m = 0
while m < n:
    if n > 100000:
        break
    x = int(input())
    if 1 < x < 10000:
        for i in range(x):
            if x % (i + 1) == 0:
                suma += 1
    if suma == 2 and x != 2:
        m += 1
        print('o')
        suma = 0
    else:
        m += 1
        print('x')
        suma = 0
```

---

The one of solution: https://medium.com/@dhruvpatel1057/generate-prime-numbers-in-python-using-segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes-245b79da6687

Comment: The first little improvement you could make is to just test those numbers that could actually be divisors (i.e. between 2 and floor(x/2)). For the sieve methods (Eratosthenes, Sundaram, Atkin) you can even find pseudo-code in the Wikipedia article.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is sample code , make a list of prime, and from this list check the number to process is getting divided or not , if it is not getting divided then it is prime else it is not

```
# your code goes here
x = int(input())
prime =[]
for i in range(2,x):
    if i not in prime:
        if prime == []:
            prime.append(i)
        else:
            check = 1
            for j in prime:
                if i%j==0:
                    check = 0 
                    break
            if check:
                prime.append(i)

print(prime)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a very naive approach for primality checking.

As a general naive but not so much method, I'd recommend using [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) as prime checker. Using `math.factorial` instead of a python loop should provide you with some reasonable speed increase while keeping the code fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

> I hear about eratosthenes sieve - but not idea, how to implement it.

That's not the sieve of eratosthenes *proper* but what people usually talk about when they mention it is that when you find a prime you go through all your candidates and remove its factors ("sieving" them out hence the name) and the new first candidate is the next prime in the sequence.

There are more efficient primality tests than sieving everything though, check the "primality test" wikipedia page for examples.

Answer (score 1):

This code will generate the amount of prime numbers the user asked for. It is very efficient, and can work out the first thousand prime numbers in milliseconds.

```
amount = int(input("Enter the amount of prime numbers you would like to see: "))

primes = []

num = 1

while len(primes) < amount:
    num += 1
    
    # If num is bigger than 1, and is 2 or is odd, and when divided by all the number from 3 to num's square root plus 1 (excluding even numbers), there is always a remainder.
    if num > 1 and (num == 2 or num % 2 != 0) and all(num % divisor != 0 for divisor in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2)):
        primes.append(num)
        
print(f"The first {amount} prime numbers are:\n{primes}")
```